# this.context is always empty in React, contextApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs

test.js

```js
export default class TestScreen extends React.Component {
    static contextType= AppProvider;

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('test',this.context);
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <AppConsumer>
        { (context) => (
           <p>{context.favoriteAnimal}</p>
        )}
      </AppConsumer>
      
    )
  }
}
```

store.js

```js
   

const initialState = {
  favoriteAnimal: "cow",
};

   

export const AppContext = React.createContext();
export const AppConsumer = AppContext.Consumer;

export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{
        favoriteAnimal: this.state.favoriteAnimal,
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }

}
```

dependencies: {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },

**this.context is empty {}**, 
in test.js. cant find a way out , any help will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you are assigning the `ContextType` to `AppProvider` which is your component instead of the context returned by `React.createContext`. Once you make this change, you don't even need to use `AppConsumer` inside of render method

```
export default class TestScreen extends React.Component {
    static contextType= AppContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('test',this.context);
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <p>{this.context.favoriteAnimal}</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: how does this.context point to the correct context, because in your class you have not assigned context to anything

Comment: @vikrant, we have assigned `static contextType= AppContext;` in class which is what it needs to point to the correct context. This is a change that has been introduced in React v16.6.0

Comment: but you are defining `contextType` not context, so how does it know it is the correct context

Comment: @vikrant, this is the way react docs prescribe it. You hv to use 'contextType'.

Comment: @Speedy11 oh, i thought it was just some random variable. thanks